# Convergence to zero of integral

Tags: real-analysis

A simple question: Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(z)| dz < \infty$. Is it then the case that $\lim_{h \to \infty} \int_{|f(z)| > h} f(z)dz = 0$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: is there a modulus on the integrand of the second integration?

Comment: do you mean whether it should be $\int_{|f(z)| > h} |f(z)|$?

Comment: yes. is it so or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to prove the statement when $f \geq 0$.

We know

$$\int f(z)dz = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \int{f(z)1_{i \leq f(z) < i+1} dz} < \infty$$

therefore the remainder of the series

$$\sum_{i=h}^{\infty} \int{f(z)1_{i \leq f(z) < i+1}}=\int_{|f(z)|\geq h}f(z) dz$$ goes to zero.

---

Edit: Another possibility is to write the limit as $\lim_{h \to \infty} \int f(z) 1_{|f(z)| \geq h} dz$  and use dominated convergence.

Comment: Can you explain, why it is enough to prove the statement for $f \geq 0$?

Comment: @Esben: The problem statement uses absolute value everywhere on $f$, except in $\lim_{h \to 0} \int f(z) dz=0$. However, from $\lim_{h \to 0} \int |f(z)|dz=0$ it follows that $\lim_{h \to 0} \int f(z) dz=0$. So we can prove this stronger statement, and in this case the problem depends only on $|f|$, not on $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $f \in L^1$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
m(A) < \delta \Rightarrow \int_A |f(z)|dz < \epsilon
$$
Now by Chebyshev's inequality, there is $M > 0$ such that
$$
h > M \Rightarrow m(\{z : |f(z)| > h\}) < \delta
$$
whence
$$
h > M \Rightarrow \left | \int_{|f(z)>h} f(z)dz \right | \leq \int_{|f(z)|>h} |f(z)|dz < \epsilon
$$

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your argument? What is, for example, the meaning of $m(\bullet)$?

Comment: $m(A)$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of $A$. I assume you are familiar with that? If not, then what kind of functions are you considering?