# Let $f$ be a function on some set $E$. If $\int_{E} f < \infty $, prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{|f|>n} f =0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a function on some set $E$.  If $\int_{E} f < \infty $, prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{|f|>n} f =0$. 
I think we should start by computing the measure of ${|f|>n}$. 
We know $m({|f|>n}) = \int_{|f|>n} 1$ .
But I don't know how to proceed or how could this be helpful.

Comment: Is $f$ nonnegative?

Comment: nothing is mentioned about it being non-negative

Comment: What is $\int_E f = -\infty$? The result isn't true.

Comment: What if we just say that f is integrable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$X\in L_1$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \int\limits_{{|X|&gt;x}} XdP =0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3506883/x-in-l-1-then-lim-limits-x-to-infty-int-limits-xx-xdp-0)

Comment: Here another solution in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/562703/121671)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3506883/x-in-l-1-then-lim-limits-x-to-infty-int-limits-xx-xdp-0 is very similar but my set is such that |f| is greater than the increasing sequence, that will make a difference I suppose?

Answer (score 2):

You have $$\int_{|f|>n}f dm=\int_E f\chi_{|f|>n}dm$$ for all $n$, $$\lim_n f\chi_{|f|>n} =0$$ and $|f\chi_{|f|>n}|\leq |f|$ for all $n$ on $E$.

If $|f|$ is integrable on $E$ (which should be your assumption for the result because otherwise it is not true as remarked in comments), you can thus just apply Lebesgue theorem.